# Adobe AIR UI performance issues when doing I/O

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, mobile, air

I'm developing an app for Android tablets @ work. It requires periodic loads of images and external SWF files.

The problem is that while the I/O is happening (using Loader class), there is a very steep frame rate drop in the UI (it actually seems to freeze the UI from half to a full second). As I understand about AS3, Flash and AIR, loads are supposed to be async, but it just doesn't feel like it.

This slowdown is so annoying that not even placing a movieclip with a "loading icon" (like AJAX applications) just stays there not animating, until the load is finished (and said icon isn't needed anymore).

Has anyone came about this problem? Any ideas how I can solve or, at least, minimize this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Even if the loading of data is done asynchronous, processing the data might be expensive.

Comment: http://blogs.adobe.com/aharui/2008/01/threads_in_actionscript_3.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, if you use a `Loader` to load a PNG or JPEG image, the image data is decoded only when it's used. This happens on the main thread and can cause your UI to stutter when creating bitmaps or textures from loaded images.

It may help to set the image decoding policy flag to `ON_LOAD`, which will decode the image in the Loader's background thread:

```
import flash.system.ImageDecodingPolicy;

...

loaderContext.imageDecodingPolicy = ImageDecodingPolicy.ON_LOAD;
loader.load(url, loaderContext);
```

Find out more about this topic in the [LoaderContext documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/LoaderContext.html#imageDecodingPolicy).  The docs state that `ON_LOAD` may use more memory.

In addition, if you're using Stage3D (Starling, Away3D, etc), it's probably actually the texture upload that's taking the time.  GPU optimization is a whole different issue, but you can look into it a bit on the [Starling Performance Optimization wiki](http://wiki.starling-framework.org/manual/performance_optimization).  The short answer is that you want to 1) upload your textures all at once (like during a loading screen), 2) you want to batch your textures together in an atlas, and 3) you can even compress textures using the Adobe ATF tools so that they upload faster and use less GPU memory.  Let me know if you'd like more details.

Answer (score 0):

For concurrency, use ActionScript Workers.
http://www.bytearray.org/?p=4423